# Unable to update data in MySQL using PHP PDO Prepared

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=site", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE site_users SET users_email_verified = :users_email_verified WHERE users_email = :users_email ");

    $stmt->bindParam(':users_email_verified', $users_email_verified,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':users_email',$_GET["email"],PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $users_email_verified = "yes";

    $stmt->execute();
    echo "done";

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

But it does not update the record.

But If I write the email directly inside `$user_email` variable (manually), like this

```
$users_email = "xyz@example.com";
```

Then the code works.

I do not understand why? How to fix it?

Comment: Because you have specified `PDO::PARAM_INT` when the address is a string. Use `PDO::PARAM_STR` instead.

Comment: I second this, this first "users_email_verified" is a INT probably 1 or 0, but the second is set as INT but is a STR because you do not have numbers there. duh.

Comment: @dExIT `$users_email_verified = "yes";` is also a string

Comment: That `$users_email` variable is never used. Meanwhile `$users_email_verified` is never defined.

Comment: @tadman `$users_email_verified = "yes";` just after the second `bindParam()`

Comment: I replaced it with `PDO::PARAM_STR` but same result

Comment: @JayBlanchard Ah, the old bind first, define second trick.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs Toby?

Comment: No errors being shown, even "done" also get echo'ed

Comment: Puzzling. Can you add your connection code to the question?

Comment: Edited my code, included the content inside `connectdb.php` file

Comment: Add echo `echo $e->getMessage();` to the `catch`.

Comment: Why did you change the code????? I thought you were using an include for the connection?

Comment: At the top of your code add `print_r($_GET);` and let us know what that says when you run the code.

Comment: I did print_r, and realized, my get value is incorrect. What a stupid mistake, I am ashamed. Really sorry for wasting your time, everyone. And thanks a lot @JayBlanchard

Comment: You may want to delete the question @Toby

Comment: I cannot delete it, but i vote'ed to close

Comment: Hmm so there was no issue that the $users_verefied_email = yes is declared after it is called as bind param ?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the binding to be [INTEGERS instead of STRINGS](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) here:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email_verified', $users_email_verified,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':users_email',$_GET["email"],PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

You should use `PDO::PARAM_STR` instead.

It also appear that you're not reporting errors, so you should check your web server's error logs for additional information.

Comment: It probably should be an int. `"yes"` is one of the most annoying things to find in a database as a boolean flag.

Comment: I replaced it, but same result

Comment: Your blind catch and ignore is not helping one bit. When you get errors, *do something*.

Comment: Edited my code, included the content inside `connectdb.php` file